# How to make Doxygen create PHP include dependency graphs?

Tags: php, graph, include, doxygen

I have set SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES, ENABLE_PREPROCESSING, MACRO_EXPANSION, SEARCH_INCLUDES, INCLUDE_GRAPH, INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH and dot related flags to YES. Class and Collaboration diagrams are shown fine.

I tried converting/filtering php

```
(require|include)(_once)? <path>;
```

statements to

```
include <path>;
#include <path>;
#include <path>
```

but none of them worked. Paths are relative to current directory and input to Doxygen.
Tried googling and searched doxygen mailing list archive and SO. No luck.

Has anyone got PHP include dependency graphs to work?

Comment: Since I didn't know what else I could do, I browsed Doxygen source code a little. In scanner.l file there is this PHPKW command defined as ("require"|"require_once"|"include"|"include_once"|"echo")[^a-zA-Z0-9_;] . Not sure how it is used really.
Also, I found that included files metadata structure should end up in m_tagFileFiles variable (tagreader.cpp). The only place where entries are inserted is endCompound() function. I haven't figured out yet how or where it is called.